# Grep to return entire file content

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to search recursively for a certain word, say MyWord, but I want to print the entire contents of all files that contain MyWord. How do I do this?

It turns out that I particularly care about binary sqlite files, both grepping them, and reading the result as a text file, rather than binary.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read the entire content of each matching file? judicious application of grep's *context* switches (`-A`, `-B`, `-C`)  may be more useful

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `find` with `grep`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -wq 'MyWord' {} \; -exec cat {} >> /path/to/outfile \;
```

This will find files containing the *word* "MyWord" recursively and quite as soon as first match found then redirect the whole file content to a new file.

Comment: How do I write it to an output file?

Comment: Thanks. I do have one more follow-up: the resulting files are sometimes binary, what's the best way to view them as text? This is Mozilla Firefox cached files from browser history.

Comment: to reading a binary file as a text file, you can add `-a` option to the `grep` above if you have GNU grep.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
sudo grep -rIlZ --exclude=${HISTFILE##*/} --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e 'MyWord' | xargs -0 cat > MyOutputFile
```

- Drop `sudo` if not looking in system directories.
- Change (root directory) `'/'` to current directory `'.'` or specific directory ie `'/home/me/stuff'`
- Remove `mnt` to include Windows files mounted under `mnt`.
- Remove `lib` to include Linux source files
- Excluding directories necessary for speed. See: [`grep`ing all files for a string takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time/1005438#1005438)
- `--exclude=${HISTFILE##*/}` is necessary if you run the command a second time or if the search string `MyWord` has ever been used in a different command before. This prevents 5 thousand history lines ($HISTFILE) from being included.
- `-r` recursive, `I` skip binary files, `lZ` outputs a zero byte after  each file name instead of the usual newline. Null (zero byte) terminators necessary for `perl -0`, `sort -z` and `xargs` used to `cat` (print out) the file contents.
- `> MyOutputFile` sends output to file instead of screen. Leave this off for output to screen.

**Note:** Missing from output is the file name, just the file content is listed.

Comment: How do I write it to an output file?

Comment: @BaronYugovich I've tested `cat > MyOutputFile` and excluded 5 thousand lines of bash terminal history file from output.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder are not so big try:

```
grep -rz '.*MyWord.*'  myfolder > output
```

if necessary add `-a`