# Ubuntu 16.04 experienced an internal error

Tags: 16.04, xorg, lightdm, gdm, history

My Ubuntu was stuck in a login loophole hence I removed lightdm and installed gdm instead. Somewhere in the instructions someone suggested to add a `sleep 1` in a file. After I did so the system has slowed down so badly. I cannot remember the filename. How would I know which file I have added this line to ? Also, how can I fix the system slowdown? I keep getting the following error as well:
[image]

Comment: it's possible I might have changed one of lightdm configs not sure as it doesn't show it after I purged it $ find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l {} \;

Comment: Sleep 1 causes the script it to pause for 1 second; place in the wrong spot and it could make that script/system perform very slowly.  If you used commands to navigate your directory, and vim/nano/any-editor to make the change, you'll find your commands in your `history`; you won't be able to see what changes you made, but the filename, or path/filename (if you didn't `cd` there) will be found in your history.  I've also modified my history to record date/time, but that's not there by default.

Answer (score 1):

---

## Read Me First

Looking at your error messages it appears to be the classic "Login Loop" caused by nVidia drivers. Follow these instructions apply `nomodeset` at boot time: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935)

Read all the instructions to see if you catch something you missed or did wrong.

If you also have Intel Integrated Graphics you can open the terminal and use:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

This will save battery life, generate less heat, give similar performance and a lot less grief.

---

## Answering your question

I don't think `sleep 1` causes any problems but to answer your question use this answer: [`grep`ing all files for a string takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time/1005438#1005438)

```
sudo time grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e 'sleep 1'
```

On my system the results are too numerous to list, so here's the abridged version:

```
$ sudo time grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e 'sleep 1' | wc -l
11.55user 8.05system 0:38.33elapsed 51%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8364maxresident)k
21161832inputs+0outputs (0major+3286minor)pagefaults 0swaps
283
```

It takes about 38 seconds to run and 283 files contain `sleep 1` or `sleep 1.0`. Most, if not all, the files were not modified by me but, released that way by the developers.

---

## Answering your comment

As far as your comment concerning:

```
$ find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This command only lists files in the current directory and all subdirectories below matching a certain file type. It doesn't modify these files in any way.

On my system the abridged version (starting from my home directory) is:

```
$ time find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec ls -l {} \; | wc -l
4026

real    0m5.614s
user    0m0.092s
sys     0m0.572s
```

There are 4,026 files found. Keep in mind on my system the `find` command caches all filenames every 10 minutes, so your results might be substantially longer than 5.6 seconds.