# Cloning an Ubuntu 18.04 physical server

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, clonezilla

I am working on cloning an Ubuntu 18.04.2 physical server, I use clonezilla for cloning, however, when I apply that image to any other servers (and of course I change the hostname and static IPs), I find that the MAC addresses stay the same, which causes a mess in my network.

It seems the MAC addresses are hardcoded somewhere, do you have any idea where I can reset these MAC addresses to use the real ones of the other servers?

Comment: You could search for a given address to find which files contain it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005437/greping-all-files-for-a-string-takes-a-long-time

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved by deleting the `/etc/machine-id` file and rebooting or just using the `systemd-machine-id-setup` utility.