# Why does my phone connection die out?

Tags: mount, android

When I connect my Android phone to my computer over USB and select the “Transfer files” option, it is mounted at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=HUAWEI_MRD-LX1N_GTU6R19802002713/`, which [is the standard location](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035122/652). However, after about ten minutes, the connection disappears. I have to disconnect and reconnect the phone. I’ve tried copying files from the phone to the computer using the standard graphical interface in Nautilus and using rsync, and both ways I got a few files copied before it timed out. Is there anything I can do to stop this happening?

Comment: You need to check logs and find out if it is Ubuntu or the phone that is the problem. Do the transfer from command line and see if you get a notice you can google on.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.